# Where can I find gedit's backup files and how to open them?

Tags: gedit

So, I just finished off the first part of an important task for school and today when I was going to continue, the document with my notes were gone. The only fragment I've got left of my file is the back up file, which doesn't show in the folder where I saved the document, but I can search for it.

Is there anyway which allows me to open the back up file, save it as a text file and continue my task? I don't really have the time for running restoring tools, which never has helped me in a satisfactory way anyway.

I wrote the document in gedit and my version of Ubuntu is 12.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Navigate to the directory where you were working and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden files in it.

There should be a file ending with a `~` and preceded by the same name of your document. Right-click on it and select to open with `gedit`. Save the information with a different name.

Comment: It **ends** with a `~`, not **starts**.

Answer (score 3):

1. Open the folder where the file was saved in Nautilus, the default file explorer in Ubuntu.
2. Click View, Show Hidden Files.
3. The back-up file should be displayed suffixed with a `~`. For example, the back-up file of `hi.txt` is `hi.txt~`.

Comment: Is it a prefix or a suffix?

Comment: @BrunoPereira: Definitely suffix. I just tried it now.